# Can the gravitational force of a many-body system be calculated via matrix operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on a software project at work that calculates the "gravitational attraction" between points in 1, 2, or 3 dimensions. This is an $O(n^2)$ runtime efficiency problem, however, if I can write it as a sequence of matrix operations, then I might be able to leverage the GPU to run my simulation which would be substantially faster. My linear algebra chops aren't that great however. Is it possible to represent the mass and position as a matrix and compute the net gravitational force for each element in the matrix as a vector?

Edit: The problem I'm trying to solve is this: Given an array of positioned-masses, compute the net Gravitational force that each mass experiences from the other elements in the array. I can easily do this using for-loops, but if it can be done using matrices then I can leverage the GPU for faster calculation.

**<sub>Non-OP edit: given masses $m_{1..n}$, positions $\underline{r}_{1..n}$. Calculate the matrix $F$, for which $F_{ij}=m_im_j\frac{\underline{r}_i-\underline{r}_j}{|\underline{r}_i-\underline{r}_j|^3}$. The goal is to do this with "simple" vector/matrix operations.</sub>**

[image: whiteboard]

Comment: You should describe more clearly what "gravitational force" problem is to be solved.  Possibly you are thinking of a multi-body problem?  It's hard to tell from the brief write-up and image.

Comment: Physics strongly suggests, that the gravitational force would proportional to the recipe of the distance in 2D, and not with the square recipe, as in 3D.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, the OP wants a general n-body simulation, thus he wants to calculate all the forces between all the bodies quickly. This requires calculating $O(n^2)$ forces.

Comment: I doubt the $O(n^2)$ complexity can be beat with out any assumptions. One assumption is to "ignore" the force between masses which are far from each other, see the Barnes-Hut algorithm

Comment: @felasfa Barnes-Hut doesn't ignore the forces between the bodies far away, it only simplifies them (for example: having 100 stars, 100 light years away, inside an 1 light year big cube, it can be calculated as if it would be a single star with summed mass).

Comment: @peterh, correction accepted. if OP wants any linear scaling, to my knowledge, I doubt any linear or log-linear complexity can be attained unless one makes some assumptions like the one made in Barnes-hut or particle mesh methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the matrix you have to fill with values is $O(n^2)$. Thus, you don't have an option for an algoritmical optimization. If you calculate optimally, you can't go below $O(n^2)$.

But you have various options for linear optimizations, namely:

- $F_{ij} = -F_{ji}$, on Newton's Laws (but also the formulas show the same). Of course, $F_{ii}=0$.
- The most complex part is to calculate $\frac{\underline{r_i}-\underline{r_j}}{|\underline{r_i}-\underline{r_j}|^3}$, compute it only once and then divide with $m_i$ or $m_j$ as you want. Note in a 2D case where gravity decreases with the recipe of the distance and not with its square, this formula will be far simpler. Although it won't be our Universe any more, it might be useful for graph visualisation tasks.
- The denominator, $|\underline{r_i}-\underline{r_j}|^3$ will be coordinate-independent, you have to calculate it only once for all the cordinates. Only the nominator, $\underline{r_i}-\underline{r_j}$ is dependent on the actually used coordinate.

---

If you are hardline in math and like the half page long formulas, you can also make a step further, derive the formulas yet another time, to calculate $\frac{da}{dt}$. This results far more complex formulas, but your simulation will be far more resistant to the time quantization error. It might be particularly useful if the precision is important.

---

If precision is not so important for you, you can also use the [Barnes-Hutt approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation). This makes your problem algorithmically simplified to $O(n\log n)$. Essentially, you create a tree of the stars by recursively halving the space where they are.

This is what also the [force simulation of the d3.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) does:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kASOnVvjeyo

Note, here you will have to count with a lot of anomalies, the worst is that stars switching tree branch result a sudden discontinuity in the force directions.

Comment: Thank you for responding with such a detailed response. If I'm understanding correctly -this would be quite difficult to solve using matrices, would you agree with that? The reason I am harping on matrices so much is that graphics cards have dedicated hardware for certain matrix operations and can run orders of magnitude faster than on the CPU.

Comment: @zero_dev You can solve with matrices, but the required operations are more complex like a vector sum. For example, the first step is to create the all the $\underline{r}_i-\underline{r}_j$ vectors for all $i\lt j$. Do your GPU has such an operation?

Comment: @zero_dev Probably you can accelerate on it a lot, but it all depends on, exactly which operations are supported by the GPU (or the library with what you are calculating it).